# "Bot domain invalid" error in web telegram login. Django

Tags: django, authentication, widget, telegram

When integrating the login via telegram for Django, I received the following error (despite the fact that all actions were done correctly)

> Bot domain invalid error

I've been tinkering with this for a couple of days and just want to share a solution.

The solution is simple and pretty funny.
Just remove

```
"django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware"
```

from MIDDLEWARE

Comment: Please don't embed the solution into the question body. You can answer your own question, please post the solutions in the answers section.

Answer (score 3):

Since Django 4.0 you can use [Cross-Origin Opener Policy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#cross-origin-opener-policy) instead of removing security middleware.

Tested on Django 4.1:

```
SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = 'same-origin-allow-popups'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact [@BotFather](https://t.m/BotFather) on Telegram and set use the `/setdomain` command to allow logins to your bot from your domain.